# Randomly select variable from list of variables JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of four variables. I want to randomly select one to use. My variables look like...

```
laneRect_one = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50);
laneRect_two = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 - 50, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50);
laneRect_three = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 * 2 - 100, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50);
laneRect_four = new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 * 3 - 150, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50);
```

So my first attempt at this was to put the variable names in an array like

```
var laneArr = ["laneRect_one", "laneRect_two", "laneRect_three", "laneRect_four"];
```

and then do `laneArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * laneArr.length)]` but quickly understood that, that will never work since I'm just using a string there's no pointers to my actual variables above.

Is there anyway I can randomly select one of the four variables I've defined above?

Comment: Just skip the quotes: `[laneRect_one, laneRect_two` etc. Better yet, abandon the variables altogether and use an array right from the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is because you're placing strings in the array, not the value of the variables. To make this work, simply remove the quotes:

```js
var laneRect_one = 'one';
var laneRect_two = 'two';
var laneRect_three = 'three';
var laneRect_four = 'four';

var laneArr = [laneRect_one, laneRect_two, laneRect_three, laneRect_four];
var random = laneArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * laneArr.length)]

console.log(random);
```

Comment: Ahhh man! I'm an idiot, thank you! I realise what I was doing wrong now :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To complete Rory McCrossan answer, you can simply fill your array with handles instead of variable names, this way, your array will contain your objects instead of simply their names.

Note that your code could have worked with a wrapping object for all your objects.

Which means:

```
let myObject = {

    laneRect_one: new Phaser.Rectangle(0, 0, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50),
    laneRect_two: new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 - 50, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50),
    laneRect_three: new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 * 2 - 100, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50),
    laneRect_four: new Phaser.Rectangle(0, game.height / 4 * 3 - 150, game.width,  game.height / 4 - 50)

}

// and then

let laneArr = ["laneRect_one", "laneRect_two", "laneRect_three", "laneRect_four"];

myObject[laneArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * laneArr.length)]];
```

But this would be way too much code for something as simple as you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
  function test() {
        var laneArr = ["laneRect_one", "laneRect_two", "laneRect_three", "laneRect_four"],
            valueToUse = laneArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * laneArr.length)];
        // do something with the selected value
        alert(valueToUse);
    }
```

For Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XDn2f/